# Image Sharing File Server on Windows Storage Spaces.

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012, network-share, windows, storage-spaces

I am working on Windows Storage Spaces File server, but I ran into this strange situation when transfer to client systems is aroung 300kb/s. 
There are two SS servers on the network - the other one is running ok (with over 100MB/s on clients).

The server that has issue is Dell R720 with 190GB of ram, 7x1Gb teamed ethernet and it is connected to MD1000 with SAS 1.5Gb cable. (the other one that is working ok uses only drives inside it). The storage spaces are set in such way that the disks from MD1000 are separated from those inside R720). On R720 there is another W2012 virtual server that is a file server which has access to physical drives (one share uses MD1000 drives other one uses R720 disks) and shares them so that the rest of virtual machines run from one of the shares.

Ive tried almost everything to troubleshoot this issue. It seems that locally drives are super fast, transfers from the other server are also pretty good... but anything that I want to share from R720 virtual file server is stuck. I don't have any idea what to do next?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your design here. Are you saying that the R720 in question is a file server for the virtual guests running on the same machine? Or are the virtual guest(s) running as a local VHD on the storage space?

Comment: R720 is a host for a virtual machine which if file server which shares vhds to the network (including R720 which also takes vhds from that virtual guest).

Comment: Just to clarify: You have a physical R720 running Storage Spaces and Hyper-V. You have a single space for the externally attached MD1000. The only thing on that space is a VHD(X) for a virtual file server, which then serve files to clients over the network. Correct?

Comment: R720 has a lot of SSD so we wanted to use that as vhd storage and md1000 is used as general storage (both are shared by that virtual windows file server from single storage space).

Comment: The confusion continues - In your question you said "storage spaces" (plural), but now you're saying that there is a single storage space.. what is it? A single space? Are you using 2012 R2 and tiering inside the space?

Comment: . yeah sorry for that. Its one stroage space (it consists of all disks from md1000 and r720 ssds -but then to create a virtual disk we chose them separately. So one virtual disk is created from md1000 drives, the second from r720 drives). Yes there is tiering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16034/discussion-between-pauska-and-piotrektt).

Answer (score 0):

For everyone having issues with brand new R720 there are two options you need to disable in adapter settings to get it working properly with virtual machines.

Do the following to resolve the slow network access issues on Dell R720 with Hyper-V installed. I faced the same performance issues while access via RDP and it was resolved by doing some configuration on Base Server Ethernet card.
Go to Start --> Run ---> write "ncpa.cpl" and enter. It will open Network Connections. In network connection select Ethernet card and open properties. When properties window appears click on "configure" button. It will open Ethernet configuration window. Under "Advance" tab find "Virtual Machine Queues" and "VMQ VLAN Filtering" and disable both options.

the answer comes from here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d5a23076-aaa8-4ba8-937f-397b8e12d6ed/windows-server-2012-dell-poweredge-r720-brand-new-but-network-is-very-very-ver-slow?forum=winservergen